# need to choose from an array of images to share or like to facebook using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I want to share to facebook a link and allow the user to choose from an array of thumbnails.  This ability of choosing the thumbnail was capable with the share button but facebook has deprecated that functionality and the share button in favor of like which to my knowledge does not allow for selection of thumbnail it only uses one.

Can someone tell me how to pass a particular array of images to the share button object 
OR 
how to enable this functionality using the facebook graph API?

Comment: So how do I pass a group of pictures to the picture node of the var obj?'code'function postToFacebook(){
      // calling the API ...
      var obj = {
             method: 'feed',
             link: 'http://www.mysite.com/test/don/poll/social/index.html',
             picture:'http://mysite/images/012412-Cameron-Diaz-50.jpg',
             name: 'I just voted for:',
             caption: 'Cameron Diaz'
     };
     function callback(response) {
     }
     FB.ui(obj, callback);
 } 'code'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you share the url link, that url link can have many og:image tags in it.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ for further information on how to setup the og meta tags in your url.